# How can I remove Zero value from list in mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I Tried so many option about this my problem but didn't now work, any idea about my problem, thanks a lot.. I want to see my System Inventory will be remove with a zero value in column ONHANQUANTITY.. see my screenshot

[Zero Inventory]

```html
View
<div id="scrollbody" style="height: 300px; overflow: scroll; width: 100%;">


    <table class="table-bordered table-striped ">



        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            
            <tr class=""> 

@if (item.ONHANDQTY != 0)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ONHANDQTY)
                    }
                </td>

      </tr>
        }
```

Comment: what do you want to display instead of 0?

Comment: isn't that 0 coming from the model(Database).

Comment: Do you want to remove the items with zero value from the list?

Comment: yes, will be remove all with a containing zero values

Comment: do you have an idea , to remove zero value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give a try to below code, you can use the if condition.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @if (item.ITEM != 0)
    {
        //Put your code here.
    }
}
```

You can remove the records which contain Item 0 from the Controller/Model. I think that be batter way.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: yes working but only zero value are eliminate, I want row data will be eliminate containing of zero value

Comment: That you have to perform in Model.

Comment: Sorry? I didn't get you.

Comment: from where you are fetching the data? can you please mention that code?

Comment: from server and then display the data in my localhost

Comment: Great! then add condition there.

Comment: what condition can i add?

Comment: can you give me an example remove zero quantity from a server?

Comment: I need to see your code, I can't explain it without.

Comment: is it of insert record ?

Comment: yup, what you need?, the controlleR?

Comment: can you please confirm? what is your question? do you what to display data or insert data?

Comment: remove all the zero values in the server

Comment: see my controller